# Pandas - update() creating "random" value?

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm trying to update `Date` from `DF1` with values from `Date` in `DF2`, whenever two columns `ColA` and `ColB` match, like so:

DF1:

```
ColA | ColB | Date 
a    | b    | 12/22/2099
a    | s    | 12/22/2099 
v    | p    | 12/22/2099 
v    | s    | 12/22/2099 
m    | p    | 12/22/2099 

DF1 = pd.DataFrame( { 'ColA': ['a','a','v','v','m'], 'ColB': ['b','s','p','s','p'], 'Date': ['12/22/2099','12/22/2099','12/22/2099','12/22/2099','12/22/2099'] } )
```

DF2:

```
ColA | ColB | Date 
a    | b    | 9/11/2022
a    | s    | 9/11/2022 
v    | s    | 10/9/2022 
m    | p    | 9/25/2022 

DF2 = pd.DataFrame( { 'ColA': ['a','a','v','m'], 'ColB': ['b','s','s','p'], 'Date': ['9/11/2022','9/11/2022','10/9/2022','9/25/2022'] } )
```

To update the dates in `DF1` I did:

```
>>> DF1.set_index(['ColA','ColB'], inplace=True)
>>> DF1.update(DF2.set_index(['ColA','ColB']))
>>> DF1.reset_index(inplace=True)  # to recover the initial structure
```

But when I print show the result of `DF1` I get this:

```
ColA | ColB | Date 
a    | b    | 9/11/2022
a    | s    | 9/11/2022
v    | s    | 10/09/2022
v    | p    | 4101580800000000000
m    | p    | 9/25/2022
```

So.. obviously what is going on with this line:

```
    v    | p    | 4101580800000000000
```

It shouldn't have been updated at all, since it only exists in `DF1` and not `DF2`? What could be going on here?

Comment: It's not "random";  it is the number of nanoseconds since the POSIX origin (1970-01-01) to 12/22/2099, so you still have your date. But there's some incorrect type conversion on pandas part.

Comment: Oh I should have thought of that, thanks. I wonder why pandas has this type conversion error, and how to avoid it

Comment: I don't have this problem, with the example you showed it works fine for me... Are you using datetime objects?

Comment: @LeoE Oh, yes I am.. I think I might track down the problem there then

Comment: With strings it works perfectly fine, with @Kenan's answer as well oh and shouldn't you have one more row with `v    | p    | 12/22/2099 ` in the final df? And the line exists in both dfs

Comment: What is your `pd.__version__`?

Comment: @LeoE Oh yes there were some mistakes when I created that example, fixed it

Comment: Anyway, this is a known and ongoing issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4094. Since it seems to promote to integer, You might consider working with that representation prior to the update (`DF1.Date.astype('int64')`) then update and convert back to a datetime with `pd.to_datetime()`

Comment: @ALollz Ohh I see, thanks for the link. Yeah, I'm running `0.24.2`.. Surprised its still an ongoing issue after so many years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run:

```
DF1['Date'] = DF1['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
DF2['Date'] = DF2['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

then `update`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert date to string before your operations:

```
DF1['Date'].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
DF2['Date'].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```